# Resizable widget android

Tags: android-widget

Is there any way we can make a resizable widget in android according to the space in home screen? 
For example if the home screen empty, i can make my large widget.
If there other icon, i want to resize my widget become smaller according to the space left in home screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common practice I have seen so far is to make several widgets in different sizes and let the user decide, which size he/she prefers. I am not sure, that there is an automated way to achieve this behavior!

Comment: Can you give some example, how to make several layout in widget? I'm new in android. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the [design guidelines][1] and the [widget basics][2] in the Android Developers Guide.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: As user i hate this solution.

Comment: @froeschli, I know it has been a while, but have you solved your issue? I made a widget this weekend after a lot of digging. If you need some help, please let me know.

Comment: @EdisonSantos thank you for your offer. I never needed this, but only tried to provide an answer for someone else. The way I understand it, since Android 4.x it's easier to achieve this behaviour...

Comment: @Edison Spencer it never was an issue of mine ;)

Answer (score 56):

With Android 3.1 this is now possible
Add the following to your appwidget-provide element
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"

Example from [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData):

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" > </appwidget-provider>
```