# how to run one mobile apps on multiple android phone?

Tags: android-layout

I was created simple currecnyConverter  apps in android But I got Problem is that when i did run this apps Nexus S(4.0",480 * 800:hdpi) emulator in Protrait is working fine but same apps run on landscape mode my button and component not fit on the screen so I want run my apps on any mode and any android version.please 
can anybody give me answer. 
Thanking you

Comment: One way I could see is to do dynamic layout-ing (allow widgets to resize) like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957953/resizable-widget-android).  Other way would be to create different layouts and swap between them on orientation change, but IMO it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the below page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You have to design the layout for landscape mode in layout-land folder with same name as in your Portrait mode.

For more info see the above page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different layout for landscape and portrait.

Follow this

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```